# Getting Access is denied : java.io.FileNotFoundException while writing to file

Tags: java, services, tomcat

**Posting this question here cause it was closed on stackoverflow and considered as off topic** 
I have a java web application. Some important info about the app:

1. The web application runs on a service.
2. You start the service and then goto http://localhost:8080/AppName to run the app.
3. The application saves some configuration in a file named config.log
4. The config.log file is placed at C:/Program Files (x86)/AppName/../config/config.log

Previously YAJSW was used to create the service that and the application would run on tomcat. But now in the new version Tomcat8.5 has been used to create the service so basically, I am installing tomcat as a windows service and them running the app on tomcat server.
When YAJSW was used there was no issue. But now after using tomcat as the service the application cannot write to the config.log file. It gets `java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied)`

I simply installed the service using following command `CATALINA_HOME/bin>service.bat install`

Is there anything additionally done when installing tomcat as a windows service that I am missing?  I got one hint from stackoverflow. That is when I changed the service to tomcat now it is running as a different user. So I need to check who the service is running as. How to check that?

Comment: I suggest you to restart your setup without messing up with sudo... Sorry for that short answer, but hope it can help you quick... Gonna go to bed!